# Wysiwyg with image copy/paste

Tags: web-applications, html, wysiwyg, copy-paste, clipboard-interaction

First, I understand that an image cannot be "copied" from a local machine into a website. I understand that it must be uploaded. I am a web programmer, and am familiar with common web wysiwyg tools such as TinyMCE and FCKEditor. My question is if there exists a program or web module or something of the sort that works will perform an automatic upload of images for a wysiwyg. I have a client that is constantly complaining about not being able to copy/paste documents with images from MS Word into a wysiwyg to create content on their website.

I have looked into TX Text Control (http://labs.textcontrol.com/) and was looking into a possibly flash wysiwyg that could upload the file automatically behind the scenes. I don't know if this exists, and google did not much help me in my search, so I thought I would ask other coders.

I am open to any sort of server technology, or browser requirements. I am looking for some browser based tool instead of an application tool such as Dreamweaver or otherwise.

If no good solution to the problem exists, I am willing to accept that at this point.

Note: This was a request from a client, and to me it seemed rather unreasonable. I decided to gather community advice instead of just tell the client 'No' and the options here have been extremely helpful and informative in presenting possible solutions.

Comment: I've implemented drag-and-drop files using Silverlight in this project http://azureslfileuploader.codeplex.com/

Comment: There is a interesting related post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c
It is about how gmail is doing this exact feature and contains a link to a jquery wrapper.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might find inspiration from [ScreenshotMe](http://dailyffs.com/index.php/share-screen/).

Basically you need different parts:

- something that takes the image out of the clipboard and uploads it to the web: this could be a java applet, flash or firefox extensions. Flash or Java would have the advantage of being cross browser
- then you use the `<canvas>` tag to display the image once it has been uploaded (use [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) to bring `canvas` to Internet Explorer)

As I pointed out in my comment, Google is discontinuing gears in favor of HTML5, have a look at [7 User Interaction - HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html).

EDIT:

HTML5 when implemented is supposed to interact with the system's clipboard. I imagine the following scenario would work:

- [paste the image data from clipboard to canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#paste-from-clipboard)
- get the canvas pixel data back as an image using `toDataURL()`: see [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)
- upload the image to server when submitting: see [Saving canvas image with PHP](http://canvaspaint.org/blog/2007/01/saving-images/)

Until HTML5 copy/paste drag&drop is implemented, you'll have to rely on [Flash](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) or a (signed) [Java applet](http://lassebunk.dk/2009/07/19/using-the-clipboard-to-post-images/) to interact with the clipboard.

Comment: I like this option, and it seems the tools might all be there are readily available with HTML 5 and the canvas element

Comment: This seems like a particularly elegant solution for the future, and does include the mention that this currently requires Flash or Java.

Comment: Does anyone know when clipboard integration is going to be implemented in the mainline builds of browsers?

Answer (score 3):

You could look into [drag & drop upload with Google Gears](http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/drag-and-drop-file-upload-with-google-gears).

Comment: google discontinued gears

Comment: Their looking into HTML 5... a replacement for Gears.

Answer (score 3):

I see this is an old thread, but in case anyone is still looking for something like this (as was I), I came across a product called [textbox.io](https://textbox.io) tonight from a company called Ephox (looks like they bought out TinyMCE as well).

Anyway, this is the first, if not only, javascript/HTML5 editor I've found that successfully pastes images from word using a proprietary plugin they call PowerPaste.  Upon the initial paste, it prompts to hit paste again in order to import the images.  Worked like a charm - only problem I had was that it's hellishly expensive for a startup like the one I'm involved in at $500+ per month (±R6,650+ per month in ZAR), which prices it out of our options unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

> I have a client that is constantly complaining about not being able to copy/paste documents with images from MS Word into a wysiwyg to create content on their website.

And this will fail. MS Word does not create valid HTML, the pages will appear broken to users of conformant browsers. Word also has some odd methods of anchoring images and flowing text that will not translate. In short, Word is a poor environment for authoring HTML.

Of course your clients probably won't accept that which brings us to option 2:

Since your client has opted for Word as their WYSIWYG editor there's very little point pasting that content into *another* WYSIWYG editor. Your optimal solution is to look into ways of automating HTML export from Word or OPen Office. This could be done using a combination of VBA and a server-side script to first convert the document to HTML (this will also write the images to disk) and then upload the combined content to the server.

Comment: HTMLTidy can do a wonderful job of fixing MS Word's worst excesses, and would let you enable copy paste of nasty MS Word HTML without too much difficulty.  I agree that the client is clearly difficult, but your solution may help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct option available in asp.net, but you can do this

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ClipboardActiveX.aspx

Comment: Just a link is not an exceptable answer.  You should add some information about the article.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML only**

You could use something that (on drag and drop) automatically creates an invisible HTML form, a file input, copy the path of the filename into the fileinput and submit the form.

You can create the form inside an invisible iframe to send it in the background without changing the current page. You know, standard Ajax procedure.

**A little help for dropping/pasting**

I don't know if HTML allows dropping file items. If it doesn't you can look at the HTML 5 specification that Google is trying to make forward.

Another option is using some kind of rich client component (Java Applet with Swing or Flash, or Silverlight, or wathever) at least to grasp the dropping of the file (or the pasting) and creating the HTML form.

**Why I prefer sending a form**

I prefer the creating of the form over the applet sending the file because it doesn't require another special port at the server or something like that.

Comment: Oh, and see the long Google Wave Video Demo. It has automatically uploaded images using Gears but their plan is to use HTML 5. So... if Google is looking that way...

Answer (score 1):

I understand your client's predicament. I am working on the same thing, but with little priority at the moment so I can't present any solutions, just a few notes.

- When I copy + paste an image from a **saved** OpenOffice document (doesn't work with an unsaved one) into a CKEDitor instance - I don't have MS Word here to test but I assume it works similarly - I get the following HTML inserted into the editor:

  `<img src="file:///C:/Users/PEKKAG%7E1/AppData/Local/Temp/moz-screenshot-4.png">`

  it might be possible to tweak a Flash or Java uploader in a way that this file can be fetched with very little interaction from the user. Being able to fetch files from the User's computer is a *horrible* security hole but it might be possible to at least pre-set an uploader to the temp directory directory.
- However, the **Canvas** method that Gregory Pakosz mentions I find the most interesting, because this way it *could* be possible to store the image on server side silently, without any upload. The same security restrictions as in the above example still apply, though: The image is on a different domain, and thus cannot be read by a script on the page. One would have to find a way around that using browser settings or writing a custom extension.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly,
your client could have any random Word
document and that some of these documents
might contain images.

What you appear to be describing is akin to content
management in some respects and to creating static
web pages in others.

I'll assUme that your client wants visitors to their
website to view such documents as HTML pages and not
as Word MIME types.

Some options:

- use Word to save as HTML.  Not the cleanest HTML
   but likely the cleanest solution.
- have your client purchase a product like Dreamweaver
   which will both import their Word document
   and clean up Word's generated HTML.
- if your client has lots of money, develop a custom
   solution using VSTO

Comment: Thanks Gerry. Your first options still doesn't solve the upload problem for the images in the Word document.

Comment: @ jW  You're welcome.

I must have missed something or have made some false assumptions.
Generally, I've taught my clients to use Windows ftp.exe to upload
from the command line.

Products like Dreamweaver automate the upload process.

My impression was that your client was attempting to maintain the integrity of the Word document, including any graphics within that document.

if it's only the graphics, your client good save the image to a file and upload that file.

Sorry, I do not have a clear picture of what your client is trying to achieve.

TIMTOWTDI =. there is more than one way to do it

Comment: Unfortunately, the client is particularly difficult. They desire is to not use ftp, but purely a web interface and be able to copy/paste a document from work and (like you said) preserve the integrity of the document, which would include the images. So an upload of the image files needs to occur to get the data there, and then the formatting from word needs to be converted into HTML. It is sort of an unreasonable assumption from a client, but I was looking for any possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if there exists a program or web module or something of the sort that works will perform an automatic upload of images for a wysiwyg

XStandard Pro will upload images to the server pasted from Word or other applications/file system.

Answer (score 0):

In looking for a similar solution, I noticed that GMail allows it *if* you're copying and pasting from a browser.

If you copy from Word it seems to know the dimensions of the image (you can see an outline of the image) but it doesn't actually paste/upload the image.

From non-Office desktop apps there appears to be no support.

So on the assumption that Google engineers have dedicated some serious time to this, I suspect that it's not do-able from desktop apps yet but maybe if you could find a quick way to save the content to the web (e.g. using Word's blog or Save as HTML features) you could then copy and paste from that, if your client is prepared to take that extra step and you're able to let them save directly to a web server.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

The WYSIWYG editor called Redactor allows for copy-pasting images directly into the editor rather than clicking an <kbd>upload image</kbd> button.

Here's [a link to their copy-paste example](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/clipboard/).

Comment: @brasofilo: Are you serious? You marked me down because (in your words) "It doesn't matter that the question is old"?