# Is it possible to paste an Image into Silverlight/Flash/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, silverlight

Is it possible to allow users to paste image data into a Website? That is, they have an image in the clipboard and can paste it into an HTML Site? (I would then somehow grab the bytes and store them - persistence isn't the problem here)

It needs to be Cross-Browser IE8, FF3.5 and Chrome 4, but I can use browser plugins like Silverlight, Flash or bare JavaScript if possible (I might even use Browser Plugins, although that would be painful to manage and IE would need ActiveX is guess...). Also since it's an internal site, I can add the site to the Local Intranet Zone in IE (not sure if that changes stuff for Firefox and Chrome).

Any chance to do this?

Answer (score 2):

With Silverlight 4, you have text-only clipboard access, but not Image data, as far as I can remember...

Answer (score 1):

Check out the lengthy discussion [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008958/wysiwyg-with-image-copy-paste). I think the end result was that this is possible using a combination of Canvas and Flash.