# Drag and drop an image from desktop to a web text editor (implementation in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to implement a web text editor able to recognize when the user drag a image file over it's editing surface and it automa(gically) starts the upload and insert the image near the cursor position.

In other words I don't want the user to do the usual "insert->image->browse->ok".

At the moment I am not very good at JavaScript. I know jQuery but I have not a clear idea about how to implement this. I don't know if there's an event handler able to help me in this situation; if not then there should be I think or web apps would miss some kind of interactivity.

I've heard miracles about HTML5 could it help me?

I've seen such things in Google Wave but that surface doesn't seem to be a form field... Google lab's black magic I guess....

Comment: I think this is OS specific... that is, you'll need a different implementation for Windows, MacOS and Linux (perhaps different for KDE/GNOME as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There's a SO bounty question about [Copy&Pasting images into a WYSIWYG editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008958/wysiwyg-with-image-copy-paste) (not entirely what you want but maybe also interesting)
- HTML 5 has [drag & drop uploads](http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload) that should be possible to extend into a "drag into web page" functionality - at least almost.

Comment: yes thank you the second link is exactly what i meant, hope that browsers won't mess too much with that

Comment: @fatmatto well, it simply won't work in many browsers, including (I think) all versions of IE :) HTML 5 is still in its very, very early days. I think the linked example, at the moment, works in Firefox > 3.6 only.

Comment: do you know alternatives? even running with different technologies?

Comment: @fatmatto very hardly. There may be some proprietary ActiveX and Java controls that offer this but I've never seen a free one, the ActiveX technology limits your range of browsers terribly, and Java Applets are .. well, it's probably down to taste :) I may be wrong, but IMHO what HTML 5 is offering is the only thing worthwhile even looking at.