# Pasting non-text data into browser-based apps

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, silverlight, copy-paste

Imagine I want a user to be able to copy-paste a selection of pixels from MSPaint into a browser-based app. Is this possible using JavaScript in any current browsers? Will it become possible in HTML5?
If not, is it feasible using something like Flex/Silverlight, or is it simply not possible at this time, and you'd have to save a file and manually upload it?

**update**: sounds like HTML5 should allow it, but that's a way in the future to be genuinely useful. Some suggestions of Java applets and Flash are mentioned, probably Flash would be preferable since parts of the web-client would probably use Flex anyway... I'd rather not have requirement for Java *and* Flash in my site.

Comment: Not really an answer, but it's a step in the right direction, I'm sure:  For inserting the data directly into html markup, see <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme">data URI scheme (wikipedia)</a>.  Unfortunately, now you're stuck between the client's image on the clipboard and encoding it into a string you can insert in an image src.  Unfortunately, outside of VB or Java or ActiveX (IWindows only), there's no way.

Comment: If I can get the data into the web-app, I can send it to the server and spit back an image of some sort... the big usability bonus is the user being able to copy-paste image data without having to save as a file themself and upload it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very thorough examination of this prior question: **[Wysiwyg with image copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008958/wysiwyg-with-image-copy-paste)**. It discusses possibly [coming behavior in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#paste-from-clipboard), as well as [Flash](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) and [Java applet](http://lassebunk.dk/2009/07/19/using-the-clipboard-to-post-images/) solutions that interact with the clipboard, and which you can then tie into JavaScript.

---

Questioner asked about Zeroclipboard's applicability. So, look at the file [ZeroClipboard10.as](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/source/browse/trunk/ZeroClipboard10.as?r=16) and you'll see the click handler supports two data formats:

```
private function clickHandler(event:Event):void {
    // user click copies text to clipboard
    // as of flash player 10, this MUST happen from an in-movie flash click event
    Clipboard.generalClipboard.clear();
    Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT, clipText);
    Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.HTML_FORMAT, clipText);
    ExternalInterface.call( 'ZeroClipboard.dispatch', id, 'complete', clipText );
}
```

The [reference for ActionScript's `ClipboardFormats`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/desktop/ClipboardFormats.html) constant indicates one of the formats is a [BITMAP_FORMAT](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/desktop/ClipboardFormats.html#BITMAP_FORMAT). So I think that's a pretty good start.

Comment: Thanks for the references. However I'm not clear how zeroclipboard is applicable, it talks about text and RTF. I'd love to see a discussion on the mechanics of how to get the contents of the system clipboard using Flash (using that library as a reference if applicable)

Comment: Updated with info on zeroclipboard! Hope that helps!

Comment: Those class references all say 'AIR only' and are part of flash.desktop. I think I'll give you the bounty, but maybe start a thread explicitly asking about Flash/Flex clipboards as well, on which your input is most welcome! Thanks.