# Pasting an image from the clipboard to silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, clipboard

Silverlight (currently 4.0) does not support binary clipboard data.What is the best approach to overcome this limitation? I have seen the similar questions\forum topica and from this,I concluded, that I must use\write some ActiveX control,but in this case this can be implemented in the ordinally web page. Can my silverlight app have any benefits? 
Has anyone faced whith the same problem and has any specific solution?

Comment: Look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2026377/511881.
You can create show html page for uploading in WebBrowser control.