# Accept pasted image in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like my users to be able to upload an image by pasting it into a form.

Is this possible somehow with Rails?

I'd like to do this safely and limit to a single picture upload, not a completely open textarea.

**UPDATE:**

**I'm looking for something like http://pasteboard.co/ that I can add into a form in a Rails app.**

Also, with a paperclip hook like https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor would be nice

Comment: how are you coping images ?!!

Comment: I think you meant drag and drop, right?

Comment: No, I mean like you paste an image into GMAIL. It's on the clipboard, and you paste it in..

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have a specific answer (`copy & paste`), I do have an answer regarding how to implement the uploading within the DOM:

---

**JQuery**

If you use something like [jquery-file-upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html), you'll be able to incorporate a GUI-based upload process to Rails

I think your question can be answered by taking this technology & applying to the specific element where you'd like to "copy & paste" the image

You can `drag & drop` images from your system into the example above. This is very similar to the copy & paste functionality you're seeking. I would personally look at this technology, and then apply it to the copy & paste procedure

---

**WYSIWYG**

You've referenced GMail as a great example of this -- but you have to remember they're allowing you to paste into a WYSIWYG editor

This is very important, as the upload image element will be handled *through* the WYSIWYG. You may be able to use this resource to help:

- [Wysiwyg with image copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008958/wysiwyg-with-image-copy-paste)

Comment: Hi Rich, good answer. I'm looking for something like http://pasteboard.co/ that I can add into a form in a Rails app. Also, with a paperclip hook like https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor would be nice

Comment: Is there any news about this?